# Strangely filled area with \tkzDrawArea

Tags: tkz-fct

I tried to draw an area under a function, but it results a strange shape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7071]
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid[color=white]
\tkzDrawX[label=$\Delta t$,noticks]
\tkzDrawY[label=$\Delta s$,noticks]
\tkzFct[domain=0:5,samples=100,id=vt]{2}
\tkzDrawArea[domain=1:4]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is: [image: failed area]

I thought of a rectangle shape. Tried the solution given in question [problem with surfaces on tkz-fct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165022/problem-with-surfaces-on-tkz-fct/165076#165076) , but the problem still exists. My tkz-fct version is 1.4c by the .sty header

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with latest texlive 2021 and `gnuplot` on PATH, and compiled with `-shell-escape`. Also tested on overleaf's texlive 2021, and the output is ok too.

Comment: That's strange, I use the latest update of TL. With the second code in the mentioned question I was able to fill the selected area, but the function's domain is overwritten. Better, but still not acceptable...

Comment: You could add `\listfiles` to preamble, run, and paste the version info from end of `.log` to the question. So I can see if versions of any included files are different.

Comment: tkz-fct.sty    2020/05/01 1.4c function

Comment: More strange: I compiled it again, and I've got the correct shape filled. But the functions graph is drawed only inside the shapes interval. The functions domain is overwritten by \tkzDrawArea, when I reset it by hand, I got the picture above again.

Comment: Edit question and paste the whole version info, not restricted to `tkz-fct`? Also can you run your example on overleaf, download the output PDF, then open and check it shown as expected?